# Facebook iPhone App Opens App Store App Instead of Web Page When Link In Post Is Tapped

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I hope this is a simple question.  I have an iPhone app that uses the Facebook Graph API to post to  the user's feed.  The method is /PROFILE_ID/feed.  I attach a link to the post, let's say www.stackoverflow.com.  When the link is clicked in a browser, the browser opens the correct web page, for example www.stackoverflow.com.  However, when I view the post in the Facebook iPhone app and tap the link the iPhone Facebook app launches my app on the iPhone if you have my app or it takes you to the App Store app if you don't and shows you the page for my app within the App Store app.  I simply want the iPhone Facebook app to open a simple web page, for example www.stackoverflow.com.

My guess as to what is going on is that when I tap on the link the Facebook iPhone app launches my app in an attempt to complete authorization.  I don't know why.  I just want the Facebook iPhone app to simply open the link and not futz with it and open some other link.

Comment: Sounds like its working perfectly, great marketing :)

Comment: I have the opposite problem :(. Can you help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444717/facebook-post-link-to-ios-app

Answer (score 4):

In the Native iOS section of your Facebook application configuration page, uncheck "iOS Native Deep Linking:". It will no longer try to find your app.

Comment: I'd been scratching my head about that. Thanks. This is very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

That's how mobile apps work, it's documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

see:

> When you have enabled iOS native deep linking in the Dev app,
>   published stories on Facebook for iOS will link back to your app if
>   they have it installed, or the Apple App Store if they do not.
>   Facebook will apply re-writing rules to redirect these links back to
>   your app. See here to see how you can implement deep linking so users
>   go to the correct content in your app.

{edit} as Anna said in the other answer, this was later made configurable